# Resources in NetBeans

Tags: java, image, netbeans, resources

Hi :) I have some problem with my resources in NetBeans. Already I add them into project, and when I run whole project in NetBeans, everything works fine :) But when I clean it and build, I have no idea where I should have those resources (app can't find my image).

Every image and font are in my packages (example: com.project.resources.images), command which I used to get it is:

```
ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(path)
```

If someone could help me it would be awesome.

Comment: Where do you put your resources? Are you building with Ant or Maven?

Comment: Dude, I dont know what are you talking about with that question (Ant or Maven?), I just build it by NetBeans (http://oi59.tinypic.com/259baf4.jpg). My resources are in packages, it's project tree: http://oi61.tinypic.com/168bi20.jpg

Comment: Well, NetBeans uses one of two build system, Ant or Maven. As you don't know which is which I suppose you are using Ant. It looks like your resources are in the sources folder. That looks fine. So, are those things are in a different package to `this` - in order for `this.getClass().getResource` to work the resources need to be in the _same package_.

Comment: Look, when I have "dist" folder where is my .jar app, when I run it, it puts me null pointer expection (no image found), after copy my resources folder into that "dist" folder it can't run too. Now I have no idea where I should copy that folder to works fine, or I just doing something wrong?

Comment: But tell me why when I run project in NetBeans everything works fine, but when I wants to run it by executeable .jar is not ?

Comment: As I said, you are searching the [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) for your resources. I don't know which package your class is in, but it needs to be in the same package as the resources you mention.

Comment: Hmm.. Ok dude ;d still I don't understand what I have to do, if we can talk on skype, to share my screen, we can fix it ;d if u dont want to, its ok :D thanks U anyway I hope i will follow ur tips and find solution :)

Comment: Please manually compare your paths for example when you are working within netbeans and when with dist folder java do not makes an exe so we have to manually place the custom made folders inside dist folder

Comment: Try to put them inside src folder

Comment: already done, still errors :)

Comment: Omg :D Junaid Hassan u made my day :) I Love you, ur solution helps me :D

Answer (score 1):

Look into the application jar (a zip format), with 7zip, WinZip or so, if you find the resources, you can do something like `getClass().getResource("/resources/someimg.png")`.

There is one issue: in a jar (and on Linux/MacOSX) the file names are case sensitive, under Windows not, so make sure about the correct case-sensitive spelling.

If it seems that on running from the IDE the files are on the class path but do not get into the jar, better pick a Maven build infrastructure with predefined directory conventions.

Comment: Dude, the only 1 solution (which I tested already, Ur solution too but dont work for me) where those resources wants to works with me is use path:
    "../resources/images/Tank.png"

Comment: @palysek if you look at joop's example, you'll see they use a leading "/" on the path, this represents a absolute path to your resource